# In ColdFusion 10, how can I tell whether OnApplicationEnd is caused by application timeout or server shut down?

Tags: coldfusion

In Application.cfc, OnApplicationEnd is called either when the application is timing out or when the server is shutting down.  However, can I tell exactly which one is the cause?  I only want to run some clean up codes when the server is shutting down but NOT when the application is timing out.  Can I actually do that?

Comment: Maybe, store the time of the last request on request end and compare that to current time in application end? if it timed out, the elapsed time would be close to the application timeout. probably not perfect, but would be more future proof than looking at stack traces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack trace is probably different in both circumstances.  Set up a test to catch an error and log the stack trace in each instance.  Then you will know what to look for when onApplicationEnd is called to determine the cause.  (You'll need to catch an error every time and search through the stack).

Of course, this comes with a big disclaimer that you're relying on undocumented behaviors that can change with any update to ColdFusion, etc, etc.  Honestly, it would be better to encapsulate the logic so it doesn't care why the application is being shut down.

Comment: +1 to "it would be better to encapsulate the logic so it doesn't care why the application is being shut down."

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!  After giving some thoughts, I believe I came up with a solution to not depend on onApplicationEnd.